# Interview Question Help

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search

I've been selected to have a technical phone interview.

The role is for a solutions engineer (a mix between consulting/advisory and software engineering). Generally, I would be meeting with clients, sometimes away from home, to gain an understanding of the problems they're facing, and then consult on which technologies to use and how to implement them.

The description briefly mentions databases, Java, and JavaScript/HTML/CSS. I have all of those on my resume, except for Java. I work on front-end mostly, but have project and internship experience with back-end.

I asked the recruiter for the company for an overview of the format or some of the specific areas they would focus on, but she wasn't sure. I'm guessing it's a new hybrid role and she wasn't given specifics. It's hard to gauge what exactly I'll be questioned on. One of the key responsibilities would be solution design and implementation of web applications.

**Could I get some advice on what to expect from such an interview, and what sort of questions I might face?**

Comment: Do you have a goal for this question? As it stands it's a little vague and doesn't have a stand out question and therefore is not really in the correct format for SE and is likely to be closed for being too broad.

Comment: @Bee Understood. Sorry for not being specific. I've done tech interviews before, but this one coming up seems to be different, and so I wasn't sure on what I should study up on.

Comment: I don't think that can be answered here. Only that company knows what they are looking for, they will ask you questions to determine if you are a fit for that particular role. If the skills you have are a match for what they want, they might make you an offer.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds to me like they're looking for someone with knowledge of full-stack development, even thought they may not realize it. In fact, they may not even fully understand what it is they'll be asking of you (full stack development can be ***very demanding*** if you're expected to understand the skill-sets for database admin, site hosting, back-end development, as well as front end dev/designer).

The interview will be more or less like other technical interview you will have had in the past. They'll ask you about projects you've worked on, whether you have familiarity with the programming language or IDE, how you would tackle a given problem, etc.

The important thing to remember is that no two interviews are alike, and no two employers have precisely the same take on what a technical role, no matter the title.

You sound like you may not have a lot of back-end experience, and this could be a problem, or it could simply be that they understand this, and are willing to allow you to learn on the job, or otherwise get training. Who knows?

Just go into it projecting confidence, and be truthful. 
If you've ever joined a company, noticed that they could solve a problem more efficiently by virtue of adopting a new product, or technology, and then helped implement said solution, then you should probably mention that.

If they ask how you'd approach a given situation, and you don't know the technical details, be honest:

> I've never addressed this particular sort of situation before, so I'd have to back our technical experts and ask for their help, however I can tell that you're going to need to load a lot of data to memory very quickly, and so we may wish to forego the use of an ORM in favor of a faster method ...

You get the point.

Many technical interviewers do not, themselves, know how to handle the problem they're asking you to solve. Showing the **willingness** to tackle something, even if you're not an expert, and **demonstrating** that you have the problem solving skills to get the ball rolling is probably the most important thing you can do.

Best of luck.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - many times I've been interviewed by people who might have been "in the trenches" a decade ago, but had shifted to a management role and hadn't kept current. They knew they wanted someone who could build a web app, and had an idea of the technologies involved, but didn't know how to do so themselves. In fact, no one on the team could. This is far from an uncommon scenario (not specifically for web applications, but you understand what I'm driving at). Is this the case 100% of the time? No, certainly not. But it happens enough that it has shaped my perceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'll be adding some of your suggestions as study points. Generally, I would be meeting with clients, sometimes away from home, to gain an understanding of the problems they're facing, and then consult on which technologies to use and how to implement them.

Comment: @onequestion - in light of this, my answer may be a little off the mark when it comes to the details, but the general principle still applies. Sadly, if you've never been "in the trenches", you may have some difficulties in suggesting technology stacks (depending on the amount of support you have, and how much technical expertise is expected of you). What lead you to apply for this role?

Comment: @onequestion - i've edited my answer to be a little more in line with what you're facing.

Comment: @AndreiROM Thanks for that. I will look over it again. The position calls for at least one year of experience programming and implementing solutions. I got a sense that training wouldn't be an issue when I talked with the recruiter. As for why I applied, I feel I have good communication skills discussing software issues and breaking things down for teams that aren't on the tech side of things. When I saw the job posting, I could see myself working with people from all sorts of companies and then programming when required.

Comment: @onequestion - Sounds to me like you have a marketable skill. A lot of technical people have trouble expressing their ideas to non-technical people. Coming up with analogies, explaining the details, or knowing when they're really getting into the weeds, and are losing their audience. Make sure you that you address how you'd talk to people and explain the challenges ahead in terms they would understand. How you've done so in the past, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Technical interviews can be all over the map**

At my current job, the technical interview consisted of a question and answer session with my manager on a variety of technology as well as a 1 hour programming test. None of it was based on algorithmic knowledge. Rather, it was all about the nuts and bolts of development, such as what `Role` means in Postgres or whether I had any experience with server deployment.

Past interviews have included everything from no programming questions at all to algorithmic brain teasers. Sometimes they have you write code on a whiteboard. Sometimes they want you to just use a text editor. In the last few interviews, they have provided a full featured IDE such as PyCharm or IntelliJ.

**Many organizations do not have a very formal or well developed process for interviewing software engineers.**

In my current job, it seemed like they took the questions for the Q&A from an old university exam. The test was just reading in some data and doing a few computations on it. One question was

> "what is dependency injection?"

One of the technical questions I encountered was

> Write code which solves a set of numbers in Polish notation

Another company I interviewed for did not know how to interview tech people, so they had us solve a custom problem. If it ran to a fairly detailed spec, they were satisfied. In that case, I was given a two sheet list of specs and told to code it, deploy it, and return it.

A friend had an interview where the interview question was to design a software engineering interview. Essentially, they did not know how to interview either so wanted the candidate to figure out how to prove their own skill.

At large firms like Microsoft, the questions will be academically inclined. They would want to see algorithm knowledge.

An important thing to remember is that the **technical interview is not an exam.** You are not expected to know every perfect answer. Plenty of interviewers do not know the answer to the questions they are asking as the process is more important. The most important thing to demonstrate a willingness to logically and enthusiastically attack the problem.